# macOS sendfile sets errno to 45

Tags: macos, sockets, network-programming

I am trying to write a simple FTP-like client-server network program on macOS using `sendfile()` function. After reading [Apple's developer Manual on this topic](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/sendfile.2.html), sadly I am still having trouble using it.

### Code

```cpp
// creation of fd
int fd = open("file_path", O_RDONLY);
off_t len = 0;

// the creation of sockets used in sendfile
getaddrinfo(NULL, port, &hints, &servinfo);
// p is iterating through servinfo (p=p->ai_next)
sockfd= socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol);
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int));
bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen);
listen(sockfd, BACKLOG);    //BACKLOG is a macro configuring pending connections

new_sockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&clients_addr, &sin_size);

// sendfile
if(sendfile(new_sockfd, fd, 0, &len, NULL, 0)==-1){
    fprintf(stderr, "server sendfile errno: %d", errno);    
    // sorry I know this is not the best way to interpret the errno
}
```

The client got a message of "connection closed by peer" while the errno code has been set to 45;

I have checked the file descriptor `fd` using `read()` and printed it, it works fine;

Comment: Errno 45 is ENOTSUPP which Apple's docs say means "The file system for descriptor fd does not support sendfile()."  So something is wrong with your `a_working_socket` but we can't know what, because you haven't shown any code or told us what that is exactly.

Comment: `printf("%s\n", strerror(45));` yields "operation not supported", which on the sendto() man page is listed as "The file system for descriptor fd does not support sendfile()"

Comment: @JohnZwinck Thank you for your information! I've added some more about the socket used in the `sendfile()`. I hope it can help in identifying my mistakes;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got the arguments backwards. According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/sendfile.2.html), error code ENOTSUP (which I assume is "operation not supported" - thanks to Jeremy Friesner for looking it up - you should print `strerror(errno)` as it's useful) means that `fd` is not a regular file.

`fd` is the first argument.

> `int sendfile(int fd, int s, off_t offset, off_t *len, struct sf_hdtr *hdtr, int flags);`
> The sendfile() system call sends a regular file specified by descriptor `fd` out a stream socket specified by descriptor `s`.

So your code isn't trying to send the file through the socket. It's trying to send the socket through the file, which doesn't make sense. Change the order.